# highcharts draw datetime a week earlier

Tags: highcharts

I'm drawing a stockChart with Highchart, here the last data set:

```
[1582844400000,32.65863464265468],
[1583449200000,29.571543938725608],
[1584054000000,18.869729784689593]
```

1584054000000 is Fri 13 March 2020

1583449200000 is Fri 6 March 2020

Now when I plot the graph, the last value is shown as Mon 9 March 2020. Which from what I understand is correct because is the default value for the properties **startOfWeek**.
So I set this:

```js
     xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
       startOnTick: true,
       startOfWeek: 5
     },
```

Thinking to set the week correctly to Friday, indeed it works, but it shows me Fri 6 with value 18,86 so it's Fri 13, but for some reason it a week before. If I set startIfWeek at 4, it shows me Th 12.

Comment: Hi @NiBE, According to the docs you should use `startOfWeek` to switch between only Sunday and Monday. You can use `tickPositioner` function to define custom tick positions, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4922/

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOfWeek) page

> **startOfWeek: number**
>
> For dateTime axes, this decides where to put the tick between weeks. 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday.
>
> Defaults to 1.

I was testing with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/hapm8kf9/1/) example from documentation, and it seems that from 0 to 4 it goes up on same week, but for some reason from 5 and 6 it goes back to previous week. Maybe it sets the average distance so the tick is not too distant from origin date.

```js
    xAxis: {
        startOfWeek: 6,
        type: 'datetime',

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b', this.value);
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
```